# DbGrid com seguinte error out of memory

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dbgrid

Estou com o seguinte erro no DBGrid.

> out of memory - dbgrid

Esse erro esta dando somente no Windows XP.

Comment: Você possui algum evento **OnDrawColumnCell**, **OnDrawDataCell** no DBGrid? O Erro é ao exibir o formulário que contém o DBGrid?

Comment: O erro acontece no evento DBGridblClick.

Comment: Pode postar o código do evento?